# Setting a:link, a:hover, etc in a css class with a DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following html code:

```
<div id="topMenu" class="spanningMenu">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="6.25%"></td>
                <td width="12.5%"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></td>
                <td width="12.5%">|</td>
                <td width="12.5%"><a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a></td>
                <td width="12.5%">|</td>
                <td width="12.5%"><a href="directions.htm">Directions</a></td>
                <td width="12.5%">|</td>
                <td width="12.5%"><a href="disclaimer.htm">Disclaimer</a></td>
                <td width="6.25%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
.spanningMenu a:link, .spanningMenu a:visited, .spanningMenu a:active {
    color: #000;
}
```

Which doesn't work.  The section above is still inheriting it's font color from  the parent container.  I understand that

I've tried a few different variations of spanningMenu a:link, and nothing seems to be working.  Google's not helping like it normally does.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you must be specifying something using `#topMenu a` somewhere else in your stylesheet.

Comment: Above code works in jsfiddle. Your are probably overwriting your style somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
.spanningMenu a:link, .spanningMenu a:visited, .spanningMenu a:active {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

If that works, you have another rule that CSS thinks is more important. Like maybe `td a { color: something }`?  You can [read in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) about the complicated rule precedence order.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding !important to the end of the style, so it looks like this:

```
.spanningMenu a:link, .spanningMenu a:visited, .spanningMenu a:active {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, its pretty simple.

```
.spanningMenu a, .spanningMenu a:link, .spanningMenu a:visited, .spanningMenu a:active {
    color: #000;
}
```